# C++: How do I dereference multiple characters from a character pointer in memory using the namelength

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char, dereference

Here is the code:

```
errorLog.OutputSuccess("Filename reference: %c", *t_current_node->filename);
```

It of course only outputs the first character. If I add something like `->filename[nameLen]` where nameLen is a valid integer of say 10 it says:

> operand of * must be a pointer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If the string is terminated with `\0`, you could use `%s` instead:

```
errorLog.OutputSuccess("Filename reference: %s", t_current_node->filename);
```

You also will need to pass the memory address of *filename*, so lose the `*`symbol.

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer. There's a check box right next to the question. Click on it to select my answer as the official.

Answer (score 2):

Use %s, and remove the `*`

```
 errorLog.OutputSuccess("Filename reference: %s", t_current_node->filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

- `%c` prints a single character.
- `%s` prints a string: all characters up to the terminating `\0`.
- `%.10s` prints the first 10 characters of a string (or less, if the string is shorter)
- `%.*s` takes *two* arguments, an integer indicating the length to print, and a string pointer.

Example for the last case:

`printf("Filename reference: %.*s", nameLen, t_current_node->filename);`